# How to send touch event to a UIView on iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uitouch

I have added a tap gesture on a view. When the view tapped, an internal method called and an alert popped up.

Now I want to send touch event to simulate finger touch on this view. How could I do this?

===============

Thanks all.

I think I should describe question clearly. I'm work on ReplayKit on iOS12. We can add RPSystemBroadcastPickerView to our custom view. In my project, click a button, RPSystemBroadcastPickerView init and add in my view, tap on RPSystemBroadcastPickerView, select items, and click Start Broadcast.

What I want to do is that When I click button, it jump to the select items interface automatically. Just like sending touch event to RPSystemBroadcastPickerView after button clicked.

Comment: What do you want the touch event to do?

Comment: try to use UIContol, you will be able to directly set action same as UIButton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIButton *btnInPicker = nil;
for( UIView *_subView in self.broadcastPicker.subviews) {
    if( [_subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] ) {
        btnInPicker = (UIButton *)_subView;
        break;
    }
}


if(btnInPicker) {
    [btnInPicker sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
}
```

but it has a issue:
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for

Answer (score 1):

first, create a RPSystemBroadcastPickerView in a position of the screen and without height and width to don't show its icon and add it to you controller(for me topController) then select most top view of  RPSystemBroadcastPickerView that is button then call its action -> theBroadcastPicker should open now without any click on screen

```
 var  broadCastPicker = RPSystemBroadcastPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
topController.view.addSubview(broadCastPicker!)
var tap = broadCastPicker?.subviews.first as! UIButton
tap.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom view and override following methods...

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

**Swift Version**

> ```
> func touchesBegan(Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?)
> ```
>
> Tells this object that one or more new touches occurred in a view or window.

> ```
> func touchesMoved(Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?)
> ```
>
> Tells the responder when one or more touches associated with an event changed.

> ```
> func touchesEnded(Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?)
> ```
>
> Tells the responder when one or more fingers are raised from a view or window.

> ```
> func touchesCancelled(Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?)
> ```
>
> Tells the responder when a system event (such as a system alert) cancels a touch sequence.

**For More details you can refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan%3AwithEvent%3A).**

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. But keep in mind that the touching mechanism in iOS has a complex structure and this block of code might not result in what you're looking for.

```
targetView.touchesBegan(.init(), with: nil)
targetView.touchesEnded(.init(), with: nil)
```